# Ubuntu cron dealing with .htpasswd file

Tags: bash, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I'm using ubuntu and apache2. Long story short, I'm password protecting a website. But the username and password will change everyday. So I've added entire month of password in /etc/apache2/.htpasswd file and I am going to run cronjob at everyday midnight to run a bash file  and delete the password line for that day. My bashfile looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash</font>
> cat /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
> sudo sed '1d' /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
```

when I run the script, it shows this
./deleteline.sh: line2 /etc/apache2/.htpasswd: Permission denied
i changed permission for bash shell as well and it works well with other files. 
So I would really appreciate it if you can tell me how I get rid of the permission error problem.

Comment: Well, is that cron job able to use the `sudo` command? What does your system log reveal about that? And what are the permissions of the `.htpasswd` file?

Comment: I already did sudo and I also set 777 to .htpasswd and it didn't work

Comment: What sense does an access mode of `777` make? Stop trying around without knowing what the issue is.

Comment: Where did you implement that cron command? Your personal crontab or the system crontab? Again: _what does your system log reveal?_ You did not answer to that question...